# Tkinter - get selected COM port from combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, serial-port, pyserial

I have a checkbox with a list of all serial ports and the user selects the one from a combobox, in order to later interface with an arduino.

Here are the interesting bits:

```
# --- functions ---
def serial_ports():    
    return serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

def on_select(event=None):

    # get selection from event    
    print("event.widget:", event.widget.get())

    # or get selection directly from combobox
    print("comboboxes: ", cb.get())

# --- functions ---



label0 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Select the COM port that the device is plugged in: ")
label0.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 8))
label0.place(relx = 0.1, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.5)


cb = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=serial_ports())
cb.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
# assign function to combobox
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_select)
```

`cb.bind()` gets the selection to `on_select()`. However, when i print the data of the user selection usuing the `on_select()` function i get:

```
event.widget: COM14 - Arduino Mega 2560 (COM14)
```

I would like to get just the COM port, for example '`COM14`'
So that it can be assigned in a variable, and later used like this:

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM14', baudRate, timeout=0, writeTimeout=0)
```

where instead of '`COM14`', i will just have my variable.

Is there a method by pySerial, in order to get just the COM port, without the full description?

Answer (score 0):

The result of `serial.tools.list_ports.comports()` is a list of `serial.tools.list_ports.ListPortInfo` instance.

So if you want to have the port names only, change

```
def serial_ports():
    return serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
```

to

```
def serial_ports():
    return [p.device for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()]
```